# sql query every week start date and end date calculated by its start date of every month

Tags: sql

I need to calculate the start date and its end date base on month start

| Week | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-Jan |
| 2 | 5-Jan |
| 3 | 12-Jan |
| 4 | 18-Jan |
| 5 | 26-Jan |
| 6 | 31-Jan |

if my month 1st week start on 1st jan and its end 2jan than my start date comes 1/jan and end date 2/jan. beause mon comes 3rd jan and my week calc. started on 1st jan sat.
like below example of cliender

| Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun | Weeks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 2 | 1st Week |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 2nd Week |
| 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 3rd Week |
| 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 4th Week |
| 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 5th Week |
| 31 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 6th Week |

I need 2 column
week start date
week end date

expected data like below

| Week | date | week start date | week end date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-Jan | 1-Jan | 2-Jan |
| 2 | 5-Jan | 3-Jan | 9-Jan |
| 3 | 12-Jan | 10-Jan | 16-Jan |
| 4 | 18-Jan | 17-Jan | 23-Jan |
| 5 | 26-Jan | 24-Jan | 30-Jan |
| 6 | 31-Jan | 31-Jan | 31-Jan |

Comment: SQL has built in date functions, including WEEK. What kind of SQL database are you using?

Comment: but my requirement is different please check whole case

Comment: Do you have two tables? (I.e. is the calendar an existing table?) Or how do you know 1-Jan is a Saturday?

Comment: no i don't have 2tables, 1-jan-2022 that why its saturday. calendar table i just give you idea.

Answer (score 0):

For MSSql and Sql Server:

If you send your date value as @yourdatevalue parameter to belowed query, it should work fine:

```
DECLARE @yourdatevalue datetime = GETDATE();

-- strip the time part from your date
DECLARE @date datetime = CONVERT(date, @yourdatevalue);

-- do the day of week math
DECLARE @start datetime = DATEADD(d, 1 - DATEPART(w, @date), @date),
        @end   datetime = DATEADD(d, 8 - DATEPART(w, @date), @date);

SELECT  @yourdatevalue AS [date], @start AS [WeekStart], @end AS [WeekEnd];
```

Also:

You can set @WeekNum and @YearNum to whatever you want - in this example they are derived from the @datecol variable, which is set to GETDATE() for purposes of illustration. Once you have those values- you can calculate the date range for a week by using the following:

```
DECLARE @datecol datetime = GETDATE();
DECLARE @WeekNum INT
      , @YearNum char(4);

SELECT @WeekNum = DATEPART(WK, @datecol)
     , @YearNum = CAST(DATEPART(YY, @datecol) AS CHAR(4));

-- once you have the @WeekNum and @YearNum set, the following calculates the date range.
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, '1/1/' + @YearNum) + (@WeekNum-1), 6) AS StartOfWeek;
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 5, '1/1/' + @YearNum) + (@WeekNum-1), 5) AS EndOfWeek;
```

Comment: for that its start my 1st week date in 27dec. as i told always start date calc. in same month week. check my expected data and calender

Comment: also calender change month wise

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: @AnkurSinghBhandari is your date column formatted as date?

Comment: sql 2017, date formatted

Comment: still not getting result as i requested. please consider calender which i attached for idea